# Bootstrap progress-bar indicator hangs

Tags: html, debugging, loading

I am new to web development and am using a Bootstrap progress-bar indicator to determine whether or not things have loaded properly on the website. However, I am stuck in a situation where the progress-bar will not go away -- and I cannot figure out for the life of me what is making it hang.

How would I figure out what it is that is not loading correctly and making the progress-bar hang? I am using Firefox for development, and a GeoDjango framework. I am loading libraries using static files... e.g.:

For CSS:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`

For JS:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/lib/bootstrap-3.0.1.min.js"></script>`

The functionality and formatting of the site looks fine -- which makes me think the scripts are loading correctly, but there is just some small piece that is holding up the progress-bar.

### EDIT 1:

I have greatly simplified the code. When I run this from my Django framework, i.e., `python manage.py runserver`, the progress-bar hangs and will not go away.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-3.0.1.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/customCSS.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
                <div id="loading" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="loading-indicator">
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 100%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both the bootstrap-3.0.1.min.css and customCSS.css files exist -- so I'm not sure what is making the progress-bar hang.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: The code is too large and involves too many directories to share here. I'm more looking for general strategies and tips or techniques that can help me pinpoint what might be going wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with code.